# How do I adjust the height of a superscript?

Tags: superscripts

I have an operation that I call `\conv`, that I defined as follows:

```
\newcommand\conv{{}^{\scriptstyle\smile}}
```

Sometimes I use it in this situation:

```
$a\conv$
```

and sometimes I use it in this situation:

```
$$\big(\prod a\big)\conv$$
```

In both cases, the superscript `\conv` is at the same level. However, in the second case, the `\sum` is so big, that the `\conv` seems to hit it at mid-level. I want it to somehow adjust to the larger size of the `\sum` so that it is up at the top of the `\big`), not so far down.

Please let me know how I can clarify my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There may a be a beeter way to do this. Using

```
\newcommand\conv{^{\scriptstyle\smile}}
```

Should do the job. The empty `{}` is responsible for the constant height of smile.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\conv{^{\scriptstyle\smile}}
\begin{document}
\[\left(\prod a\right)\conv\]
\[a\conv\]
\end{document}
```

I suggest using `\[   \]` instead of `$$    $$` and `\(   \)` for `$   $`. Also instead of using static `\big(` and `\big)`, it is better to use dynamic `\left(` and `\right)`

[image]

**EDIT** Different version:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\conv}[1]{{#1}^{\scriptstyle\smile}}
% \newcommand\conv{^{\scriptstyle\smile}}
\begin{document}
\[\conv{\left(\prod a\right)}\]
\[\conv{a}\]
\(\conv{}\conv{}\)
\end{document}
```

Comment: But then it doesn't let me put $\conv\conv$.! 
Here is the error message that I get:
Double superscript.
\conv ->^
         {\scriptstyle \smile }
l.58 \item $a\conv\conv
                       =a$ for all $a\in A$.
?

Comment: use `\(\conv{}\conv\)`

Comment: OK, now I'm getting a different error:<inserted text> 
                }
l.52 ...ary operations on $A$, $\comp$ and $\conv$
                                                   are unary operations on $...

?

And here is what I put in the preamble:\newcommand{\conv}[1]{{#1}^{\scriptstyle\smile}}

Comment: @MathMastersStudent: While code snippets are useful, your complete problem will be better understood and reproduced by us only if you provide a complete MWE and we will be able to answer better. I think you can start a new question with your current problem (pl. add a complete MWE).

Comment: Of course your suggestion of using `\conv{}\conv` doesn't work when the first `\conv` follows a large delimiter.

Comment: @egreg I don't follow. That method is ugly I accept, but I didn't get your comment properly. Can you pl.elaborate?

Comment: @HarishKumar Did you try `\Bigr]\conv{}\conv`? The first will be raised, the second won't. (I mean with the first version.)

Answer (score 3):

A method for being able to use `\conv\conv` is the following

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand\conv{^\bgroup\scriptscriptstyle\@conv\conv}
\def\@conv#1{\smile\@ifnextchar\conv\@conv\egroup}
\makeatother
```

I've used `\scriptscriptstyle`, as `\scriptstyle` is redundant.

Here's an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\conv{^\bgroup\scriptscriptstyle\@conv\conv}
\def\@conv#1{\smile\@ifnextchar\conv\@conv\egroup}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
$a\conv$

$a\conv\conv$

$\Bigl[a\Bigr]\conv$
\end{document}
```

[image]