# Super(sub)scripts at half level

Tags: subscripts, superscripts

Is there a way to achieve that the superscript or subscript for that matter, 
appear at half of a variable? either at left or right..

I found this answer, but doesn't seem to apply 
[How do I adjust the height of a superscript?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51844/how-do-i-adjust-the-height-of-a-superscript)

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want the baseline of the superscript to be at half the height of what appears before, you can use the code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\halfscript}[2]{\settoheight{\hght}{#1}{#1}\raisebox{.5\hght}{$\scriptstyle{#2}$}}

\newlength{\hght}

\begin{document}
\[
\halfscript{A}{x}\halfscript{a}{x}
\]
\end{document}
```

This produces the output

[image]

On the other hand, if you want the script symbol to be *centered* with respect to the previous character, use the code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{calc}

\newcommand{\halfscript}[2]{\settoheight{\oneheight}{#1}\settoheight{\twoheight}{$\scriptstyle{#2}$}{#1}\raisebox{.5\oneheight-.5\twoheight}{$\scriptstyle{#2}$}}

\newlength{\oneheight}
\newlength{\twoheight}

\begin{document}
\[
\halfscript{A}{x}\halfscript{a}{x}
\]
\end{document}
```

This will produce the output

[image]

Note that the `calc` package is needed to subtract heights.

To get the script on the left, use the macro

```
\newcommand{\prehalfscript}[2]{\settoheight{\oneheight}{#1}\settoheight{\twoheight}%
    {$\scriptstyle{#2}$}\raisebox{.5\oneheight-.5\twoheight}{$\scriptstyle{#2}$}{#1}}
```

Then the command `\prehalfscript{B}{x}\prehalfscript{a}{x}` will produce

[image]

Comment: It works nice! how can the script appear on the left?

Comment: Edited my response to include the left scripts.

Comment: You might consider using `\mathchoice` if you want this to work in nested scripts: `A^{\halfscript{B}{x}}` renders `x` too large.

Answer (score 5):

There's `\valign`. Enjoy and don't ask.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\halfscript}[2]{%
  \mathord{\hbox{% ensure math mode
    \valign{%
      \vfil##\vfil\cr
      \hbox{$#1$}\cr
      \hbox{$\scriptstyle#2$}\cr
    }%
    \kern\scriptspace
  }}%
}
\newcommand{\prehalfscript}[2]{%
  \mathord{\hbox{% ensure math mode
    \kern\scriptspace
    \valign{%
      \vfil##\vfil\cr
      \hbox{$\scriptstyle#2$}\cr
      \hbox{$#1$}\cr
    }%
  }}%
}

\begin{document}

X $\halfscript{A}{x} \halfscript{a}{x}$ X

X $\prehalfscript{A}{x} \prehalfscript{a}{x}$ X

\end{document}
```

[image]

The `\valign` command is the “transpose” of `\halign`, so we are doing an aligment of vertical boxes, centered with respect to the largest one; the reference point will be at the bottom of the box, which will be the final glue.

An improved version will center the “halfscript” with respect to the height of the nucleus, rather than height and depth, which is similar to what happens to subscripts and superscripts.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\halfscript}[2]{%
  \mathord{%
   \setbox\z@=\hbox{% ensure math mode
      \valign{%
        \vfil##\vfil\cr
        \hbox{$#1$}%
        \xdef\halfscript@dp{\the\prevdepth}%
        \kern-\prevdepth
        \cr
        \hbox{$\scriptstyle#2$}\cr
      }%
      \kern\scriptspace
    }%
  \dp\z@=\halfscript@dp\box\z@
  }%
}
\newcommand{\prehalfscript}[2]{%
  \mathord{%
    \setbox\z@=\hbox{% ensure math mode
      \kern\scriptspace
      \valign{%
        \vfil##\vfil\cr
        \hbox{$\scriptstyle#2$}\cr
        \hbox{$#1$}%
        \xdef\halfscript@dp{\the\prevdepth}%
        \kern-\prevdepth
        \cr
      }%
    }%
  \dp\z@=\halfscript@dp\box\z@
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

X $\halfscript{A}{x} \halfscript{a}{x}$ X

X $\prehalfscript{A}{x} \prehalfscript{a}{x}$ X

X $\halfscript{p}{x}$ $\prehalfscript{d}{x}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: May I ask, is this all official expl3 syntax?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Ask Frank.